# Changing Android imageButton draws new image behind old image

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I am writing a program which deals with playing cards. Here, I am trying to show the player's hand. I have six imageButtons `sixCard0` -- `sixCard5` which will each display one card from the player's hand. Each has its default image (of a question-mark card) set in xml:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sixCard0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/card0" />
```

I want to change this image to an image representing the card that is already in the player's hand when the activity starts. The cards are kept in `CribbageApplication.cardList`. In the activity's `onCreate(...)` I have:

```
findViewById(R.id.sixCard0).setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier(Card.getImageName(((CribbageApplication) this.getApplication()).getCardList()[0]), "drawable", getPackageName()));
findViewById(R.id.sixCard0).invalidate();
```

Accessing these values is not where I am having a problem. My problem is that when I run the app, the default image is still displayed on the imageButtons. See: http://s23.postimg.org/cbmxchonv/Screenshot_2014_05_28_22_15_25_1.png

In debugging, I decided to use a smaller image as the imageButton's default image. (In this case it is an icon with text that reads "Set Hand" which I sourced from elsewhere in my program.) Now when I run the app you can clearly see the default "Set Hand" icon there with the new larger card image behind it! See: http://s12.postimg.org/3ytgenaz1/Screenshot_2014_05_28_21_48_10_1.png

Can someone please tell why this is happening?

EDIT: I have fixed the problem. I should be using `setImageResource(...)` instead of `setBackgroundResource(...)`. In the example above, a typecast is required to call this function:

```
((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sixCard0)).setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier(Card.getImageName(((CribbageApplication) this.getApplication()).getCardList()[0]), "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setImageResourse not setBackgroundResourse

```
findViewById(R.id.sixCard0).setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(Card.getImageName(((CribbageApplication) this.getApplication()).getCardList()[0]), "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Thanks! I had seen an answer like that but Eclipse kept telling me that `setImageResource(...)` was not available. I realize now that I was missing a typecast. It should be `((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sixCard0)).setImageResource(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

`android:src` and `android:background` are two different things.

To fix your problem:

Use `setImageResource()` instead of `setBackgroundResource()` .